# Фиксированный отсортированный массив

Tags: алгоритм, структуры-данных

Есть отсортированный по убыванию массив **фиксированного размера**. На вход подаётся множество элементов, которые могут модифицировать или не модифицировать массив по следующим правилам:

1. если пришедший элемент меньше либо равен минимальному элементу массива, то переходим к следующему элементу
2. если пришедший элемент больше минимального, то находим необходимую
   для него позицию (чтобы массив оставался отсортированным) и
   записываем его на эту позицию, сдвигая меньшие элементы, причём
   бывший минимальный пропадает, но размер массива сохраняется.

Другими словами, необходимо поддерживать отсортированным массив фиксированной длины.

Есть ли какая-нибудь эффективная структура данных для этой задачи?

Comment: Классический двунаправленный связанный список

Comment: @AntonShchyrov не совсем подходит, так как автор хочет эффективную структуру данных

Comment: Да есть, называется сбалансированное дерево поиска, например красно-чёрное дерево (пример: `std::set` в C++, `TreeSet` в Java), авл дерево, декартово дерево (кажется оно самое простое для самостоятельной реализации), сплей дерево, вероятно и другие есть

Comment: Простите, но у вас в условии задачи уже жестко задана структура данных - массив. О чем тогда вопрос? Другая структура данных либо не будет реализовать интерфейсное поведение массива вообще, либо будет делать это неэффективно.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рассмотрел два варианта.

1. Как предлагали в комментариях, сбалансированное дерево поиска.
2. Если постоянная отсортированность не настолько важна, как замена минимального - можно подумать о *неубывающей пирамиде*, в которой первый элемент - всегда минимальный.

Хорошо вписывается пирамида и в том отношении, что она легко реализуется с помощью массива, так что не нужны никакие дорогостоящие выделения/освобождения памяти. Конечно, заранее сказать нельзя, нужно ставить эксперименты - но кажется, что при нормальной реализации пирамида будет эффективнее дерева.

Можно подумать о *Фибоначчиевой пирамиде*, которая может оказаться еще эффективнее - но она существенно сложнее в реализации, а выигрыш может дать, скорее всего, при больших размерах данных и при большом количестве операций.

Все они хорошо описаны в ["Алгоритмах" Кормена и К<sup>о</sup>](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1794-2.html).

Answer (score 0):

Эффективная и стандартная структура для такой задачи - `heap` (куча, пирамида). Например, в С++ это `std::make_heap/std::pop_heap/std::push_heap`. Там используется фиксированный массив, но лежат элементы в порядке "деревянном". То есть имеет смысл, если новые данные поступают часто, а выводить весь массив по порядку надо не очень часто.

Если есть условие, что массив должен быть всегда массивом по порядку, то выбирайте или вектор, если копирование элементов быстрое, или список, если элементы "большие и тяжелые".